# MPI Latency measuring

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, latency

I am trying to understand some aspects of the MPI. 
During the creation of the program, which is to measure latency between send/recv of two processes, I was faced with strange effects. 
I tried to measure the result of many iterations, and received a response that matches the other benchmarks. Then I decided to display values ​​after each iteration and was surprised: they ranged between four values ​​that have not changed. I also drew attention to some very high values.

The code that calculates the value of latency and sample values is below:

```
int main()
{
    MPI::Init();
    Proc_Rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        latency_test(Proc_Rank, 1, 0);

    MPI::Finalize();
    return 0;
}

void latency_test(int Proc_Rank, int Iterations_Num, int Size)
{
    double Total_Time, Latency;
    double t1, t2;

    char *Send_Buffer = new char[Size];
    char *Recv_Buffer = new char[Size];
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
        Send_Buffer[i] = 'a';
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
        Recv_Buffer[i] = 'b';
    }

    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Barrier();
    t1 = MPI::Wtime();
    for(int i = 0; i < Iterations_Num; i++){
        if (Proc_Rank == 0){
            MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(Send_Buffer, Size, MPI::CHAR, 1, 0);
            MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(Recv_Buffer,Size,MPI::CHAR,1,
                                 MPI::ANY_TAG);
        }
        else if (Proc_Rank==1) {  MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(Recv_Buffer,Size,MPI::CHAR,0,MPI::ANY_TAG);
            MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(Send_Buffer, Size, MPI::CHAR, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    t2 = MPI::Wtime();

    delete []Send_Buffer;
    delete []Recv_Buffer;
    Total_Time = t2-t1;

    if(Proc_Rank == 0){
        Latency = (Total_Time / (Iterations_Num * 2.0)) * 1000000.0;
        printf("%10.10f\n", Latency);
    }
}
```

Part of the result:

```
5.4836273193
1.0728836060
0.9536743164
1.0728836060
0.4768371582
0.9536743164
0.5960464478
6.5565109253
0.9536743164
0.9536743164
1.0728836060
0.5960464478
0.4768371582
0.4768371582
```

Why are 4 fixed values randomly repeat? And why there are rare very large values?

Comment: What MPI implementation, network, rank placement are you using? It just seems your timer has a granularity of `0.119209 us`. Also: the C++ binding in MPI have been deprecated by the standards for ages and are now officially removed.

Comment: @Zulan, thanks for reply! I have multiprocessor AMD Opteron cluster, with two processors on each node. I'm using this parameters for running    mpirn -np 2 -mca btl self, vader -npersocket 2 ./mpi_test. So, it means, that two processes shold be placed on one socket. Implementation is OpenMPI 1.10.2. I know, that it's very old version, but when i'm trying OpenMPI 2.0.2 it gives much more slower results. Can this effect depend on compiler, which i'm using for making of OpenMPI?

Comment: When i'm running this program using OpenMPI, it gives me results it that way: 12.8042884171
1.7514685169
1.6943085939
1.8496066332
1.6870908439
2.2621825337
1.5635741875
10.5821527541
1.9228318706
1.6321428120
1.6000121832
1.4359829947
1.6195699573
1.7214333639
1.5967525542
1.5596160665
1.4917459339

Comment: If you are trying to do a proper evaluation, you should use established MPI benchmarks, such as [OSU Micro Benchmarks](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/benchmarks/) and [Intel MPI Benchmarks](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mpi-benchmarks).

Comment: Not related to your question, but i think you don't need two buffers. You can use single buffer for send/receive since you are using blocking calls.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Zulan, the resolution of the timer used by `MPI_Wtime` is not infinite. You can query the timer resolution by calling `MPI_Wtick` (`MPI::Wtick` in the C++ bindings). Measuring a single ping-pong round that lasts less than a microsecond is prone to very high statistical uncertainty, especially since the OS jitter, which is the random delay of the process execution due to other OS activities or processes being scheduled on the same CPU, could be several microseconds. No respectable MPI benchmark would do a single ping-pong round with empty messages.

As a side note, you are using a wildcard receive (`MPI_ANY_TAG`) in one of the processes. Those tend to be slower than fully-specified receives, especially when it comes to network equipment.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Could you just explain why the results of OpenMPI 2.0.2 were much slower than the old version (1.10.2)? From what it can depend, given the fact that I run absolutely the same program with the same parameters?

Comment: Not all versions of Open MPI are created equal. There are substantial changes in some parts of the 2.x branch compared to the 1.x branch.